# Javascript Send GET Request

Tags: javascript, php, get, request

I am creating a script & I need it to be able to send a GET request. The only thing is, it will be a script that is entered into the Url bar into people's browsers. Below is the PHP code I have.

```
<?php

$first = $_GET["first"];
$last = $_GET["last"];

$myFile = "names.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $first;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = ":";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = $last;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "\r\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

fclose($fh);

?>
```

I really need help. Thanks to everyone that helps me out.

Comment: where do you need help ?? you need to specify your problem

Comment: The problem is that I am not sure how to send a GET request through Javascript. I just need an example or something. Thanks.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: But does that work in the browser's Url? Like, when you enter in for example, "javascript:alert('message');"?

Comment: `javascript:alert('message');` is not a GET request

Comment: I know. I was providing an example of what I meant by putting Javascript into a browser's Url bar.

Comment: Why do you need to do this with Javascript? Just putting the URL into the address bar sends a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
javascript:x=new XMLHttpRequest();x.open("GET", "//example.net/yourpage.php?fname=John&lname=Smith", true); x.send()
```

See the documentation on [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Basically, you just take the code you would have written in a Javascript block, and put it after the `javascript:` URL scheme prefix.

Comment: It works when I do it on my site, but when I do it from other sites it doesn't. Is there any way to get it to work from other sites?

Comment: Maybe it's the AJAX same-domain restriction. Do you get an error in the Javascript console?

Comment: I got this error code: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.net/page.php?fname=John&lname=Smith'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.                      Example.com is the third party site & the Example.net is my site.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you're accessing another domain, you need to prefix it with `//`. It will then use the same HTTP or HTTPS protocol as the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var fname="bily";
var lname="doc";
window.location.href = "phppage.php?first="+fname+"&last="+lname;
```

on php page you can use GET method to retrieve.